# Polymer paper-dialog on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: dialog, polymer, mozilla

Polymer paper-dialog doesn't work on Mozilla Firefox. On Chrome all is ok. But on Mozilla all text and messages are on the same page. I want to click a button and see paper-dialog in this moment.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser may not support Polymer.
Watch this documentation will be useful:

https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/resources/compatibility.html